# Trying to combine two power source into a single micro usb output

Tags: lithium

I had a power bank which is has 2 usb port that can charge simultaneously, the problem is both of it discharge at 5.1v and 0.5a.
I would like to use 2 usb plug combined them in parallel into a single micro usb output.So it would be 5v and 1a.
And also I planned to use that custom made cable with my power adapter, 1st adapter output 5v 1a and another one 5.2v 1.8a.
What did you think, can it be done and use safely ?
Do I need to use a controller ?

Comment: This is what I want to do with so many low amperage chargers, please let me know if you find any cables that one side with multiple female micro-usb and the other male micro-usb. It's hard to work with those tiny wires to make a custom one.

Answer (score 1):

In principle you could do what you ask using two DC-DC converters each having 5 V input and 2.5 V isolated output, rated at 2.5 W or greater, and connecting the outputs in series. This would give you 5 V at a maximum current slightly less than double the current available from each 5 V source - slightly less because the converters will be less than 100 % efficient.

However in practice it would almost certainly be cheaper and easier to buy or make a better power bank that can supply 5 V at 1 A - I'm pretty sure most of them can.

Are you sure it's the power bank that is limiting the current available from each output to 0.5 A, rather than the device(s) you are connecting to it that are only drawing 0.5 A?